# Derivation of Born-Infeld (BI) for D-brane

Tags: electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, string-theory, action, branes

I am trying to reproduce derivation of the [Born-Infeld](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born%E2%80%93Infeld_model) (BI) action for D-branes as it is presented in

> R.J. Szabo, *BUSSTEPP Lectures on String Theory,* [arXiv:hep-th/0207142](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0207142).

In particular, I don't understand how the inverse Green function $N^{-1}$ of the Laplace equation appears in the boundary action (page 70 eq. 7.29)

$$ S_{\rm b}[\xi, A] ~=~\frac{1}{2} \int_0^{2\pi} \! \mathrm{d}\theta \left( \frac{1}{2\pi\alpha^{\prime}}\xi^{\mu} N^{-1}\xi_{\mu} + \mathrm{i}F_{\mu\nu} \xi^{\mu}\dot{\xi}^{\nu}\right). \tag{7.29} $$
Can anyone explain it?

Comment: You might find more details from the original derivation in the paper “Non-linear electrodynamics from quantized strings” by E.S. Fradkin and A.A. Tseytlin.